# Un/bound methods in Cheetah

Tags: python, cheetah

Is there a way to declare static methods in cheetah? IE

**snippets.tmpl**

```
#def address($address, $title)
<div class="address">
<b>$title</h1></b>
#if $address.title
$address.title <br/>
#end if
$address.line1 <br/>
#if $address.line2
$address.line2 <br/>
#end if
$address.town, $address.state $address.zipcode
</div>
#end def

....

other snippets
```

**other.tmpl**

```
#from snippets import *

$snippets.address($home_address, "home address")
```

This code reports this error: `NotFound: cannot find 'address'`. Cheetah is compiling it as a bound method, natch:

**snippets.py**

```
class snippets(Template):

    ...

    def address(self, address, title, **KWS):
```

Is there a way to declare static methods? If not, what are some alternative ways to implement something like this (a snippets library)?

Comment: syntax highlighting for cheetah is not great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://packages.python.org/Cheetah/recipes/staticmethod.html) seems to have some relevant information, but I'm not in a position to try it out myself right now, sorry.

Specifically, you should just be able to do:

```
#@staticmethod
#def address($address, $title)
```

...and have it work.

(If you didn't know, [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) is a built-in function that creates a... static method :) It's most commonly used as a [decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). So I found that page by Googling "[cheetah staticmethod](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=cheetah+staticmethod)".)

Comment: ah, my search for 'cheetah static methods' didn't get me that. I'll go test this

Comment: Yeah, it tends to narrow down considerably if you use the function name rather than the phrase.